# classpath of a directory inside jar

Tags: java, jar, liquibase

In liquibase docker command line parameters , Is it possible to give classpath of a directory inside jar ?

like if I have to give the location of BOOT-INF/classes/changelog-1.xml inside application.jar
can I give
--classpath=application.jar/BOOT-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-classpath-when-class-files-are-in-jar-file-in-java/

> The below specific command is used to set the classpath for any jar files separated by semi-columns.

```
C:> set CLASSPATH=classpath1;classpath2...
1. C:> set CLASSPATH=.;C:\dependency\framework.jar

2. //Add multiple jars
$ set CLASSPATH=C:\dependency\framework.jar;C:\location\otherFramework.jar  

3. //* means all the files with .jar extension
$ set CLASSPATH=C:\dependency\framework.jar;C:\location\*.jar
```